# How to do a $\varepsilon-N$ proof of convergence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Suppose that $\{a_n\}$ converges and suppose that $\{b_n\}$ diverges. Prove that the sequence $\{a_n+b_n\}$ diverges. *Hint: try a proof by contradiction*.

Started with assuming that there exists $N_1$ such that $a_n<\varepsilon$ and $N_2$ such that $b_n>\varepsilon$.

Not sure if on the right track and where to go from here.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773). I tried to improve your post using TeX (for better readability). Please check whether these edits did not unintentionally change the meaning of your post. Also, please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose to the contrary that $\{a_n+b_n\}_n$ converges, say $\lim_n (a_n+b_n) = L$. We are also given that there is $a$ with $\lim_n a_n = a$. Then

$$\lim_n b_n = \lim_n(a_n+b_n)- \lim_n a_n = L -a$$

exists, contradiction with the hypothesis.